# Find all complex roots of $(z+1+i)^4 - 1 + i =0$.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Find all complex roots of $(z+1+i)^4 - 1 + i =0$.

**Attempt:**
I got
\begin{align*}
(z+1+i)^4 &= 1 - i \\
(z + \sqrt{2} e^{i(\frac{\pi}{4})})^4 &= \sqrt{2} e^{i(-\frac{\pi}{4})} \\
z + \sqrt{2} e^{i(\frac{\pi}{4})} &= \sqrt[8]{2} \exp\left(i\frac{-\frac{\pi}{4} + 2k\pi}{4}  \right) \\
z &= \sqrt[8]{2} \exp\left(i\frac{-\frac{\pi}{4} + 2k\pi}{4}  \right) - \sqrt{2}e^{i(\frac{\pi}{4})}
\end{align*}
for $k=0,1,2,3$.

Am I true? If not yet, how to find it?

Comment: Looks right to me, with the $\sqrt{2}$ coefficient added to the last term.

Comment: It is true? Okey Sir thanks! Thanks also for the edit.

Comment: I think you are correct! Curious on why you want to find the roots of this polynomial. An exercise?

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Yes it is my first exercise in complex analysis

Comment: First exercise : skip the next few and find yourself some complicated ones. You are good at this!

Comment: @TeresaLisbon great to hear that thanks. Maybe I want to learn about the next, such like complex function

Comment: Keep going. You can write the above proof attempt as an answer below and accept it, it is correct.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Okay I'll do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got
\begin{align*}
(z+1+i)^4 &= 1 - i \\
(z + \sqrt{2} e^{i(\frac{\pi}{4})})^4 &= \sqrt{2} e^{i(-\frac{\pi}{4})} \\
z + \sqrt{2} e^{i(\frac{\pi}{4})} &= \sqrt[8]{2} \exp\left(i\frac{-\frac{\pi}{4} + 2k\pi}{4}  \right) \\
z &= \sqrt[8]{2} \exp\left(i\frac{-\frac{\pi}{4} + 2k\pi}{4}  \right) - \sqrt{2}e^{i(\frac{\pi}{4})}
\end{align*}
for $k=0,1,2,3$.

Comment: Yes, great! +1. After some time, accept the answer, so the question can be closed.

Comment: Once again, thanks for your support!

Comment: You are welcome. I appreciate your format of posting questions the way it has been done. This will be a model to new users.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Sorry to ask. That's means that there are four solution right? Call it $z_0,z_1,z_2,z_3$?

Comment: Indeed, it means that there are four solutions. They are all different numbers.